# access property of property of control in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I've a button for which I did: `buttonLinkObject.Font.Underline = true`

`buttonLinkObject.GetType().GetProperty("Font").GetValue(buttonLinkObject, null)` returns

```
Bold: false
Italic: false
Name: ""
Names: {string[0]}
Overline: false
Size: {}
Strikeout: false
Underline: false
```

Now, how do I access the Underline property directly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object to [FontInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the `Underline` property:

```
buttonLinkObject.Font.Underline = true;

FontInfo fontInfo = buttonLinkObject.GetType().GetProperty("Font").GetValue(buttonLinkObject, null) as FontInfo;
if (fontInfo != null)
{
    bool isUnderline = fontInfo.Underline;
}
```